# Error without rendering an object: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a project based on React and Django on backend. And I am getting this error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {bookId, title, image, price, countInStock, qty}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

This is my hook:

```
function CartScreen({ match, location }) {
   const bookId = match.params.id
   const qty = location.search ? Number(location.search.split("=")[1]) : ""
   const dispatch = useDispatch()

   const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart)

   useEffect(() => {
      if (bookId) {         
         dispatch(addToCart(bookId, qty))
      }
   }, [dispatch, bookId, qty])

   return <div>Shopping cart</div>
}
```

This is action creator:

```
export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
       const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/books/${id}`)
    
       dispatch({
          type: "CART_ADD_ITEM",
          payload: {
             bookId: data.id,
             title: data.title,
             image: data.image,
             price: data.price,
             countInStock: data.count_in_stock,
             qty,
          },
       })
     localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
    }
```

This is reducer:

```
export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
       switch (action.type) {
          case "CART_ADD_ITEM":
             const item = action.payload
             let index = -1
    
             state.cartItems.forEach((x, i) => {
                if (x.bookId === item.bookId) index = i
             })
    
             if (index !== -1) {
                state.cartItems[index] = item
                return {
                   ...state,
                   cartItems: state.cartItems,
                }
             } else
                return {
                   ...state,
                   cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
                }
       }
    }
```

But the suprising part is that the action creator is showing the error despite of the fact the that action is created and cartItems is getting dipatched into state. But after that this error shows up.

N.B.- The state is updated but cartItems is not stored in localStorage.

[Action creator showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzQ3f.jpg)
[cartItems loaded in redux store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFiDk.jpg)

Previously from the CartScreen hook I was returning more lines of code but since it didn't seemed to have any effect on the error so i removed it for testing purpose.

I have also seen other queries related to this but nothing seems to work because actually I didn't understand from where the error is getting genrated.
I am new to react so pardon me for any silly mistake.

Thanks for any help or suggestions regarding this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found out my mistake. It was Header.js where I had written {cart.cartItems} (array of objects) instead of {cart.cartItems.length}. Just a silly mistake which React was not showing.

Lessons I have learnt:
React doesn't always tells you exactly from which component the error is getting generated especially when it's associated with another library such as redux in this case.
So we have to manually find out which component is behaving unexpectedly after the state is getting updated.

My Header.js if anybody is interested :)

```
function Header() {
   const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart)

   const dispatch = useDispatch()

   const logoutHandler = () => {
      dispatch(logout())
   }

   return (
      <header>
         <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark" expand="lg" collapseonselect>
            <Container fluid>               
               <Col md={5}>
                  <SearchBox />
               </Col>

               <Navbar.Toggle />
               <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                  <Nav className="xl-auto" id="userNav">                                          
                     <LinkContainer to="/cart">
                        <Nav.Link className="mx-1">
                           <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" /> Cart ({cart.cartItems})
                        </Nav.Link>
                     </LinkContainer>                     
                  </Nav>
               </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
         </Navbar>
      </header>
   )
}
```